# In SQL how to use a max column value to filter query results

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I want to group this data by Description-Name pairs and return how many entries with a given Description-Name pair had in the data.

Additionally, I want to filter out all entries that are not from the most recent (max) timestamp. In this case that is 2021-02-15 19:00:00.000.

I am able to extract that timestamp with a simple select max(date), but I cannot use max(date) in a where clause to filter the data.

One approach would be to the first query for the max(date) and then use that in a second query where I can then use the max date in a where clause, though I want to do it in a single query. Would greatly appreciate advice and I'd be glad to clarify anything.

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and don't post text as image also see about a [mre]

Comment: Hi, your question is a typical use of [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) clause in sql commands.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to select the maximum timestamp in a sub-query.

```
select description, name, count(*)
from data
where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from data)
group by description, name
order by description, name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5afbfa510eec88daa027c0872efcf14b) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Hey really appreciate it, didn't know a sub-query was a thing as I'm new to all this but that exactly solves my problem.